# Firebase: How to get authenticated user's token using firebase api after successfully logging in with email?

Tags: javascript, firebase, cookies, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase JS SDK [(SDK setup page)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) on `login.html` where registered users enter their credentials and then  [firebase.auth()signInWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#sign_in_existing_users) is called to log them in.

#### Login.html

```
HTML:
    Email: <input type="email" name="login-email" id="login-email"> <br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="login-password" id="login-password">
    <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit">

SCRIPT:
    var loginEmailInput = document.getElementById('login-email');
          var loginPasswordInput = document.getElementById('login-password');
          var loginSubmitBtn = document.getElementById('login-submit');
    
    loginSubmitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              var email = loginEmailInput.value;
              var password = loginPasswordInput.value;
    
              firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user) {
                window.location.href="profile.html"
              }).catch(function(error) {
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                result.innerHTML = '<strong>'+ errorCode +' !</strong> + ' + errorMessage
              });
          })
```

After successfully logging in, user is redirected to `profile.html`. On the profile pg, I would like to get details about the authenticated currentUser only so I try the following code, but that does not work:

#### profile.html:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
        //If token is returned, then get user details:
        .then((idToken) => {
        
        //store currentUser in user
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

        var displayName = user.displayName;
        var email = user.email;
        var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
        var photoURL = user.photoURL;
        var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
        var uid = user.uid;
        var providerData = user.providerData;
          
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Error occurred.
        })
```

this `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()` does not work. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the `getIdToken` method, you can simply check, the `currentUser` Object.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user) {   
   // User is signed in. 
    var displayName = user.displayName;
    var email = user.email;
    var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
    var uid = user.uid;
    var providerData = user.providerData;
} else {   
   // No user is signed in. 
}
```

if user has logged in, `firebase.auth().currentUser` will always contain user information.